# Can you syphone water underwater by using outside water pressure?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, flow

If you have an underwater bio-sphere; is it possible, with the correct plumbing,to use the deeper outside water pressure to create a perpetual flow of water towards the shallow end where the pressure is less? If so, can this flow be used to spin turbines for electrical generation? I provided a picture to give a visual idea to the concept. I am aware that the plumbing/syphon is probably incorrect.

Thank you for your time to whomever is replying

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a nice idea but wouldn't work as described. The pressure at any position (height/depth) inside the siphon tube will be exactly the same as the pressure at the same height/depth in the surrounding ocean - so the water inside your siphon would be in the same equilibrium as the water in the outside ocean and wouldn't flow up or down.

If you could find a place in the ocean where there were upwelling or downwelling currents naturally occurring in the sea, then you could potentially make it work - but it might just be simpler in that case to have propellers mounted on the outside of your habitat.

Or if you can find a high temperature undersea vent then you could run the system by funneling the hot rising vent water into your tube - of course then the water would rise up the tube so your generator/turbine would gave to be designed to operate in the reverse direction.

Comment: Wouldn't the inside pressure of the bio sphere which would be different from the outside water pressure effect the pressure in the siphon to not be the same equilibrium of the outside water pressure? Especially if the temperature of the biosphere effects the temperature of the water in the siphon? I also forgot to mention that the siphon would use a pump to get the flow started. Would that have any effect to destabilizing its equilibrium to the outside pressure?

Comment: So long as the siphon is a closed tube (otherwise it would leak into your biosphere) then the equilibrium I described will hold. A pump would cause the water to flow in the siphon temporarily (you could chose either direction) but the flow would decay rapidly. Of course if your siphon **does** leak into the biosphere then you can extract energy from the water flow - but only until the biosphere is flooded. As there is basically no energy source/sink in the situation you are describing, for it to work would require a perpetual motion machine - which is always physically impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Penguino! Much appreciated!